# Passing Numbers to a Sympy function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, parameter-passing, sympy, eval

I am practicing Python from Codewars. One of the questions was to take a function as an input given in string from, differentiate it and use the other input given as an integer and return the result. For example lets say the inputs are

```
stringf=x**2+2x
inputint=3
```

def differentiate(stringf,inputint) should return 8. I managed to do this by using Sympy and eval. However when I take the derivate of the function with sympy.diff it converts a regular lambda function to something else which you cannot pass arguments. For example you can do f(1) in below code but you cannot do deffunc(1) it throws the error "TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable" because the type of deffunc becomes "<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>" after sympy.diff.

```
def differentiate(equation, point):
    import sympy as sym
    
    f=lambda x:equation            #turn the string into a formula with x
    
    x= sym.symbols('x')    
    deffunc=sym.diff(f(x),x)       #differentiate with respect to x
    
    strfunc=str(deffunc)           #convert the function to a string to be used in eval
    x=point
    f=eval(strfunc)

    return f
```

I found a workaround by simply converting it to string then using eval but I was wondering is there a better way to pass the 'point' into the 'deffunc'?

Comment: sympy has its own form of `eval`, that takes a string and returns a sympy expression.

Comment: Don't confuse python functions, sympy expressions, and strjngs. Study the sympy basis, especially the gotchas before trying anything fancy.  Also check if codewars expects you to use plain python.  Sympy may be a cheat in that context.

Comment: codewars doesn't allow sympy, you were right. I need to find something within the means of regular python capabilities without any additional libraries. However, that is not the question. I want to learn how to pass a parameter to a function. You do this when you define the function as def samplefunction(parameter1, parameter2) but how about when I define the function as x= lambda x:x**2. Then how can I use pass a parameter (not an array, I know you can use 'map' with arrays)

Comment: ok it turns out you can actually pass parameters to a lambda function by simply calling f(1). But sympy converts the function to something else after differentiation. I printed types for f and deff they were "<class 'function'>" and "<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>" respectively. Then the question becomes how to pass a paramter to sympy